# Why does mass not matter on how quickly an object falls?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, acceleration

I've seen all the mathematical proofs and physics demonstrations in vacuums. 
However, for example, if a hammer falls to the Earth it falls very quickly. But, it can be interpreted another way. The hammer doesn't fall to the Earth, the Earth falls to the hammer.
Then, on the moon, (since the smaller gravitational acceleration) the moon falls a lot slower to the hammer than the Earth falls to the hammer.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but mass doesn't matter because the gravitational force is proportional to he gravitational mass, which is equal to the inertial mass.

Comment: By the logic of your potential explanation, if someone dropped a hammer on the other side of the earth at the same time as you dropped one, neither hammer would fall.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "neither hammer would fall"

Comment: They do fall, and my logic did not apply anything like that.

Comment: If the Earth falls to the hammer, which hammer does it fall towarsd?

Comment: It depends on the perspective. The earth is falling to the hammer, and the other hammer is falling to the earth.

Answer (score 0):

that is because the gravitational force depends on mass o the earth and the object and the object which which fall like hammer have negligible mass as compared to the mass of the earth. therefore the force exerted is the same.